# How to dynamically show line numbers in gutter according to lines in text editor box using Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, line-numbers

I need to print out accurate line numbers in the sidebar of my app using only vanilla JS.

The line numbers must auto-increase and decrease as lines are added and removed from the editable text area.

Currently it's creating new DIVs but new `<code>` tags would be spectacular. Unfortunately `<code>` tags print out on the same line instead of incrementing vertically.

My current code looks like this:

html:

```
<div class="textBox" contenteditable>
  <code>
    This div can be edited in browsers that support HTML5.
  </code>
  <code>
    Please edit this text and add more lines to see what needs to happen.
  </code>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  let totalLines = 1;
    function updateGutter(allLines) {
      const toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < allLines;) {
    i += 1;
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = 'r' + i;
    newDiv.className = 'ansbox';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `${i}.`;
    toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);
    document.getElementsByClassName('gutter')[0].appendChild(toAdd);
  }
}

function unEqual(linesTotal) {
  if (linesTotal !== totalLines) {
    totalLines = linesTotal;
    updateGutter(totalLines);
  }
}

const getLength = function getLength(element) {
  const linesTotal = element.querySelectorAll('div').length + 1;
  unEqual(linesTotal);
};

const box = document.querySelector('.textBox');
box.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  getLength(box);
});
```

But it creates an output that looks like this:
[image]

I hope this is more explanatory. :-) *** Also There's an updated FIDDLE at https://jsfiddle.net/Tranq/heyaxtd5/4/ ***

Comment: Provide a working example.

Comment: Can't tell with the limited code you provided, but it sounds like you want the count to continue where the previous one left off. If that's the case, then declare `i` ouside the `updateGutter` function so that the same variable is used for each call.

Comment: What is `allLines` and what's your HTML look like?

Comment: Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Tranq/heyaxtd5/

Comment: Put all relevant code directly in the question, with any unnecessary code removed.

Comment: Is the Fiddle not sufficient?

Comment: No, it's not, because if JS Fiddle is unavailable for whatever reason where are future visitors supposed to find the code? Stack Overflow questions should be self-contained (link to external demos by all means, but put the relevant code in your question) in order to be easier for the community to answer and for others to understand in order to derive use from the answers supplied.

Comment: Ok, how much "relevant" code should I post? Is the HTML required? The entire JS file? Only certain functions? I want to provide the right thing but I don't know what's expected. Sorry.

Comment: As much as required to fully and accurately represent the issue, but no more. Your demo output doesn't show the image you posted in the question, so I don't know where the difference is.

Comment: "As much as required to fully and accurately represent the issue, but no more." It's probably rather obvious that I'm too new to this to know what's required. ****The example is an editable text box. You need to create new lines to create the issue. It isn't static so it won't look like that out of the box. If it was static I could just dictate how many line numbers are required but that's not how a text editor works.

Comment: As for how much code you need to add, and to expand a little on what squint already advised, I'd recommend looking at the "*[mcve]*" (and perhaps also the "*[ask]*") guidelines.

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas. I'll read those now.

Comment: @TimBiden: Then give instructions on how to reproduce the issue. This is all about effective communication. Consider that others don't know anything about what you're doing, except that which you tell them.

Comment: May I ask what parts of the question are necessary? Looking at your code, and the JS Fiddle, you have quite a complex method for updating and wrapping content, for counting lines...are you amenable to a complete change? Is there anything in the demo that is required to be kept, or can it (mostly) be thrown away and re-written? Are the `<code>` elements required? Does the line-number have to be selectable, or would it be preferred if it wasn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using some [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) magic?

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/heyaxtd5/2/

CSS:

```
pre
{
    counter-reset: thecodenumbering;
}

code
{
    counter-increment: thecodenumbering;
}
code:before
{
    padding-right:5px;
    content: counter(thecodenumbering);
}
```

HTML:

```
<pre>
    <code>A line of code</code>
    <code>A line of code</code>
    <code>A line of code</code>
    <code>A line of code</code>
    <code>A line of code</code>
</pre>
```

**UPDATE:**

changed a bit your JS, it seems to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/heyaxtd5/5/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work as a text editor. You can't edit the text that says `This div can be edited in browsers that support HTML5.`.Thanks though. :-)

Comment: @Tim Biden: Add attribute contenteditable to the `<pre>`, http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/.

Comment: @TimBiden see update

Comment: Bingo!!! The Fiddle works. Thanks Sharky!

Comment: @TimBiden glad to help :D

Comment: I feel dumb that it was all over 2 lines. But it works so I'm stoked.